# What is the best trick to handle null values in Recycler-view onBindViewHolder?

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

I handled many exception regarding null/index-outof-bound etc. But i am thinking that this is not right way to go like if/else , so anyone can guide me How to handle all null condition in onBindViewHolder?

```
@Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
        {
            if (holder instanceof CustDtlsHolder)
            {

//  >i am getting here lots of null values below 


                if(position < arr_custdetails.size())
                {
                    String dateInString = arr_custdetails.get(position).getLastVisitDate();
                    Date date = null;
                    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
                    try {
                        date = formatter.parse(dateInString);
                        SimpleDateFormat formatter2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy");
                        update_date = formatter2.format(date);
                        update_date = update_date.replace("/"," ");
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (NullPointerException e){
                        update_date="null";
                    }

//> same getting null values below as mention above.

                    ((CustDtlsHolder) holder).txt_mbr_date.setText(update_date.substring(0,2));
                    ((CustDtlsHolder) holder).txt_mbr_year.setText(update_date.substring(3,6)+ " "+update_date.substring(7,11));
                    ((CustDtlsHolder) holder).txt_mbr_name.setText(arr_custdetails.get(position).getFullName());
                    ((CustDtlsHolder) holder).txt_mbr_email.setText(arr_custdetails.get(position).getEmailAddress());
                    ((CustDtlsHolder) holder).txt_mbr_phone.setText(arr_custdetails.get(position).getMobileNumber());
                    ((CustDtlsHolder) holder).txt_mbr_avgSize_val.setText(""+Math.round(arr_custdetails.get(position).getAvgBasketVal())+" , "+Math.round(arr_custdetails.get(position).getAvgBasketQty())+" "+"Units");
                    if(arr_custdetails.get(position).getLast90dayVisit() == null || arr_custdetails.get(position).getLast90dayVisit().equals(""))
                    {
                        ((CustDtlsHolder) holder).txt_mbr_avgVisits_val.setText("");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ((CustDtlsHolder) holder).txt_mbr_avgVisits_val.setText(arr_custdetails.get(position).getLast90dayVisit()+ " in Last 90 days");
                    }
                    ((CustDtlsHolder) holder).txt_mbr_noofvisit.setText(arr_custdetails.get(position).getMbrVisitCount());

                }
            }
```

Comment: make one common method in Util class and pass the value of the your variable like Util.checkNull(arr_custdetails.get(position).getFullName()); it will return flag true or false if it return true then set default value for your holder item otherwise set whatever you get from the string.

Comment: You can add function inside your ViewHolder and call it bind(), then you can manipulate your codes there and it will make your code clean.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this way also it will be helpful for you...please try this.

**model:**

```
 public class YourModelName{

    private String mobileNumber="";
    private String fullName="";
    private String emailAddress="";
    private String avgBasketVal="";
    private String avgBasketQty="";
    private String last90dayVisit="";

    public String getMobileNumber() {
        return mobileNumber;
    }

    public void setMobileNumber(String mobileNumber) {
        this.mobileNumber = mobileNumber;
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }

    public void setFullName(String fullName) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }

    public String getEmailAddress() {
        return emailAddress;
    }

    public void setEmailAddress(String emailAddress) {
        this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
    }

    public String getAvgBasketVal() {
        return avgBasketVal;
    }

    public void setAvgBasketVal(String avgBasketVal) {
        this.avgBasketVal = avgBasketVal;
    }

    public String getAvgBasketQty() {
        return avgBasketQty;
    }

    public void setAvgBasketQty(String avgBasketQty) {
        this.avgBasketQty = avgBasketQty;
    }

    public String getLast90dayVisit() {
        return last90dayVisit;
    }

    public void setLast90dayVisit(String last90dayVisit) {
        this.last90dayVisit = last90dayVisit;
    }

}
```

Comment: I think this is not proper. Add null check in your setter method.

Comment: This is alternative option I have posted one more I already suggested to him in comment he can choose whatever he feel suitable.

Answer (score 1):

Edit @dilip answer:

```
public class YourModelName{

    private String mobileNumber="";
    private String fullName="";
    private String emailAddress="";
    private String avgBasketVal="";
    private String avgBasketQty="";
    private String last90dayVisit="";

    public String getMobileNumber() {
        return mobileNumber;
    }

    public void setMobileNumber(String mobileNumber) {
        if(mobileNumber != null)
        this.mobileNumber = mobileNumber;
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }

    public void setFullName(String fullName) {
        if(fullName != null)
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }

    public String getEmailAddress() {
        return emailAddress;
    }

    public void setEmailAddress(String emailAddress) {
       if(emailAddress != null)
        this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
    }

    public String getAvgBasketVal() {
        return avgBasketVal;
    }

    public void setAvgBasketVal(String avgBasketVal) {
       if(avgBasketVal != null)
        this.avgBasketVal = avgBasketVal;
    }

    public String getAvgBasketQty() {
        return avgBasketQty;
    }

    public void setAvgBasketQty(String avgBasketQty) {
      if(avgBasketQty != null)
        this.avgBasketQty = avgBasketQty;
    }

    public String getLast90dayVisit() {
        return last90dayVisit;
    }

    public void setLast90dayVisit(String last90dayVisit) {
      if(last90dayVisit != null)
        this.last90dayVisit = last90dayVisit;
    }

}
```

If your string value is null then return "".

Hope this may help you.

Comment: can i check multiple exception using this.

Comment: @charisharma you can change setter method what you want. like in array setter method you can check size.

Comment: actually i am using gson so i dont need to set data , i am using only get method.

Comment: As per your answer i have tried in get method also its working fine but one is disadvantage : if i want to check null than i have to place all condition in get method so it may be increase your model size , i am looking less code to handle this situation.

Comment: Just add a condition in setter method. When gson convert json to pojo then setter method execute

Answer (score 1):

Above answer which modifies the Model class didn't work for me.

This is what I came up with

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(HomeViewHolder holder, int position)
{


    String title;

    try {

        title = myList.get(position).getTitle();

    } catch (NullPointerException e) {

        title = "Null";

    }

    holder.tvTitle.setText(title);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For string values you can use android's TextUtils, and fyi you can even set null in textView.setText() method:

```
CustDtlsHolder custDtlsHolder = ((CustDtlsHolder) holder);
String value = arr_custdetails.get(position).getLast90dayVisit();
if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(value) {
    value += " in Last 90 days";
}
custDtlsHolder.txt_mbr_avgVisits_val.setText(value);
```

But as has been written, you should better create bind method for clearer code. Usually in Java projects I use ButterKnife and create some base classes like that.

BaseRecyclerAdapter:

```
public abstract class BaseRecyclerAdapter<T> extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BaseViewHolder> {

private List<T> items;
private OnRecyclerItemClickListener<T> onRecyclerItemClickListener;

public BaseRecyclerAdapter(List<T> items) {
    this.items = items;
}

@Override public void onBindViewHolder(BaseViewHolder holder, int position) {
    T item = getItem(position);
    holder.bind(item);
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        if (onRecyclerItemClickListener != null) {
            onRecyclerItemClickListener.onItemClick(this, item);
        }
    });
}

protected final View getViewHolderView(ViewGroup parent, @LayoutRes int itemLayoutId) {
    return LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(itemLayoutId, parent, false);
}
// ... other base methods such as getItemCount(), setItems, etc.
```

BaseViewHolder:

```
public abstract class BaseViewHolder<T> extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

protected abstract void bind(T item);

public BaseViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
}

public final Context getContext() {
    return itemView.getContext();
}
```

And usage:

```
final class MyAdapter extends BaseRecyclerAdapter<MyItem> {
MyAdapter(List<MyItem> items) { super(items); }

@Override public BaseViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new MyViewHolder(getViewHolderView(parent, R.layout.item));
}

class MyViewHolder extends BaseViewHolder<MyItem> {
    @BindView(R.id.txt_date) TextView txtDate;

    MyViewHolder(View itemView) { super(itemView); }

    @Override protected void bind(MyItem item) {
        txtDate.setText(getContext().getString(R.string.item_created, DateTimeUtils.formatDate(item.date)));
        // put your null checking here
    }
}
```